# thead height issue in opera browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opera

I have use the following code snippet to render the table header with in the div

Code snippet[HTML]:

```
<body>

    <style type="text/css">       

        .r-table{           
           border: 0 none currentColor;
           outline: medium none currentColor;
           table-layout: fixed; 
           width: 100%;
           max-width: none;
           color: #AAAAAA;
       }

        .headercell{
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-bottom-width: 3px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-right-width: 1px;
            border-top-width: 1px;
            outline: medium none currentColor;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0 0.5em;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;    
            background: #050505;
            border-bottom-color: #ADCD48 !important;
            border-left-color: #303030 !important;
            border-top-color: #303030 !important;   
        }


    </style>

    <div class="headercontainer">

        <table class="r-table" cellspacing="0.25px" border-spacing="0px;">

            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:30px;" />
                <col style="width:150px;" />
                <col style="width:150px;" />
                <col style="width:150px;" />
                <col style="width:150px;" />
                <col style="width:150px;" />
                <col style="width:150px;" />
                <col style="width:auto;" />
            </colgroup>


            <thead>
                <tr class="columnHeader">
                    <th class="headercell" style="height:45px;">TEST</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>        

    </div>

</body>
```

in this case thead height set as 48px in allbrowser exept opera.
How to achieve this 48px as thead height in opera browser

Comment: Please post the complete code, which is necessary, e.g. your `.r-table` element.

Comment: Here with i have attached the jsfiddle link :  http://jsfiddle.net/Zn2d8/  . Can you please check this  with layout of th in opera and other browser.  you can see the different th height in opera and other browsers.

Comment: It works for me well under Mac OS X.

Comment: i have use windows 8 os, Can you please ensure this in windows 8

Comment: What version are you using?